# The RestHighLevelClient cannot be used with elasticsearch 7 BulkProcessor. Which client should be used?

Tags: elasticsearch

The elasticsearch 7 documentation -
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk-processor.html

mentions the client to be used as follows-
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html

Here HightLevelRest Client cannot be used with bulkprocessor in elastisearch7.

This is different from what they had suggested in elasticsearch 6 - 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.4/client.html

Could someone mention which client they use with bulkprocessor in elasticsearch 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestHighLevelClient can be used with ElasticSearch7 BulkProcessor. You should take a look at the source code. The only change is in the RestHighLevelClient bulkAsycn method. It now takes an additional parameter RequestOptions. So previously the signature was -

```
BulkProcessor.builder(restHighLevelClient()::bulkAsync, listener);
```

The new signature is something as follows-

```
BulkProcessor.builder((request, bulkListener) -> restHighLevelClient.bulkAsync(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, bulkListener), bulkProcessorListener
            );
```

Hope it helps